# Retrieving date time in Firebase with regard to timezone

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have some variable stored as date.

When I change the date in my device, sometimes it changes the response from firebase return date adjusted to proper timezone, but sometimes my device needs restart, for firebase to adjust to the timezone change (especially on Android devices).

How can I make sure, that I don't need to make any restarts, and firebase will return me the date variable adjusted to my new timezone?